# I am not able to create a sub directory in wordpress's multisites network

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, apache2

I am using AWS EC2 t2.micro + mysql + php + apache2 + wordpress.
I want to make it to multi sites network with sub-directory mode.
But, I meet always 404 not found by sub-directory.

I tried every solutions what is explained from internet.
Please help me to solve this problem.

This is `.htaccess` file under `/var/www/html/wordpress`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And, This is `wp-config.php` in same directory.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'testpassword!' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_general_ci' );

define('AUTH_KEY',         's5cGJ/+=7N)Dh@#Omqb^_wq|#9_qy-K`EQ, W4H>fhOQyT|P|GyeQpAYLEc1^Kre');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '3zV!-o-eRiP,TP#>cuPtNZ*#v<^q+(j!#o;b{7U:nw4u2$mr!Y<&4>Tv{/PwRe9w');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'n!ZrQ<?8X!!No?7jMTA+$3W!q}/!2<bI&o%S;$-DA-w+EyuSt]oOtmL(Cjv.;=L>');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'RY<a|yCd*Emt8FIi1YTde[%6J.08@Q}6QXe[q.P37S^4gIi wy5yvTK|Cd(]|P9]');
define('AUTH_SALT',        ';P+JBkfUZ^&2|fYE^)R8|sz^^|PGIr6lJEV#^Qe.iT!Yx>snhVFt~DNrw-J+KV6D');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '8`j23oHkndO9Mwzug%&~(nY{#@[Tnq{=BwVcZ%P;|_N8Bgw>5O_@2-J0Yq#yr(5)');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'U|3Zc,_m*l]pi@y5tjl&O&7zr:7$/+|,7M-s/v~A<1<f$^5~.=VWfL7?~R5Jy8,l');
define('NONCE_SALT',       ']G1LrA9*% ]QL6Wrmg`_CPR@UQ~FZ=|q `(KO).!>M6Z=eU8>I;K7KJs^xVq3(l;');

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'testdomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

I just changed password and domain name to hide original info.

I think the cause is the wordpress php code is not able to create physical subdirectory.
mysql show tables what are created for new site.

Please give me any advise. I spent 1 week to solve this problem.

Comment: explain with examples what are your current and expected results

Comment: @MohammedElhag I created sub directory in wordpress network sites menu as new site like `http://testdomain.com/it'. But, It shows always 404 not found.